# 30m CAT6 cable drops connection about every minute

Tags: networking, cable

I moved into a new shared flat and got the worst situation for my room. I cautiously bought a 30m CAT6 cable to ensure that I won't run out of cable when I lay the cable throughout the flat. Now I tried it serveral times connecting the cable and I always notice the same thing:

After about every 1 to 2 minutes the connection drops for a second. All programs show "Not connected", Windows shows "not connected" then instantly "Identifying ..." and in less than a second I'm back online for a few minutes.

It's not that bad but since I do play games this is a no-go. I do play games where a connection loss is fatal thus making it unplayable.

What could this be? The cable is made purely out of copper as it states on the Amazon product page and it got a rating of 4.8 stars saying it's a great cable. Might it be faulty? Issue with the network chip or the router maybe? No one of my flat mates are complaining about connection losses. It's just me.

Comment: Was it pre-manufactured with RJ45 connectors also or did you get the cable only and then you crimped the connectors yourself ?

Comment: Premanufactured cable. I won't mess with that stuff on my own.

Comment: What devices (make, model) is the cable plugged into on both ends? Does it travel alongside power lines? Does it travel through obvious RF noise areas (like next to your cordless phone)?

Comment: It's connected from a Fritz Box 7362 SL to my computer (some Ethernet chip, good enough usually - was a relatively expensive Mobo). The cable does run along the walls in the corners / edges. I can't really imagine that the powerlines are close enough to interfere. It's about 30-40cm below the cordless phone dock.

Comment: Are the corners sharp corners? There is a bend radius you need to follow with ethernet cables.

Comment: They are. But I laid out the cable pretty generous. This shouldn't be an issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

Test the cable (point blank) with a laptop to exclude actual cable problems (Get the cable, a laptop, go to router location and connect directly there).

Make sure the cable connectors connect well with the router and the end PC. Improper contacts can cause this.

Even if it is CAT6, it can be subject to EM interference from power lines or power-related devices.

Make sure the cable is not along power lines, make sure it does not intersect power transformers or devices that have high power transformers (old like TVs).